# Listing only specific values in OneToOneField Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models

I have two models. The first one is a tools/models.py and the second one is projects/models.py.
The tools model has a OneToOneField which refer to my projects model.

```
from django.db import models
from projects.models import Project


# Create your models here.
class ScrewDriver(models.Model):
   screwdriver_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
   screwdriver_project = models.OneToOneField(Project,on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, null=True, blank=True)
```

But I don't want to show the project's name if the project status **IS 'DONE'**

```
from django.db import models


# Create your models here.
class Project(models.Model):
    status = [
        ('0', 'Paused'),
        ('1', 'On Going'),
        ('2', 'Done'),
    ]
    project_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    project_status = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=status)
```

So how can I set a condition before adding the models.OneToOneField ?

Thanks..

Comment: Please include code, not images of code.

Comment: See http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can work with the [**`limit_choices_to=…`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.limit_choices_to):

```
from django.db.models import Q

class ScrewDriver(models.Model) :
    screwdriver_name = models.CharField(max_Length=100, unique=True)
    screwdriver_project = models.OneToOneField(
        Project,
        on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        limit_choices_to=~Q(project_status='2')
    )
```

This however only has effect on validating the *form* (so in `ModelForm`s and on the Django admin pages). You still can select `Project`s that are done with the Django ORM, and furthermore if a project is later set to done, it will still link to that project.

Comment: I tried limit_choices_to=({'project_status': 2}) and it worked.
Thank you so much

Comment: What if i want to select everything except that has 'project_status: 2' ?

Comment: @AliEzzeddine: that is the `~` part in `~Q(project_status=2)`, this *negates* the status. That is why I used a `Q` object instead of a dictionary :)